# AuthorizeAttribute Implicitly Typed populated role with enum

Tags: c#

I have Roles in Enum

```
public enum Role
    {
        Undefined = 0,
        Public= 1, 
        Private = 2,
       ..... list continues...  
    }
```

I am setting access using AuthoriseAtribute for API

```
 [HttpGet]
 [AuthoriseUser(AllowedRoles = new[] {  Role.Private, Role.Public })]
 public <anyreturnType> Get(int id)
 {
   // some stuff
 }
```

Which works fine. But I like to make it more dynamic and optimize the code so I don't have write the whole long list of roles.

So I am trying to achieve this.

```
[HttpGet]
 [AuthoriseUser(AllowedRoles = new[] {  All Roles except Undefined })]
 public <anyreturnType> Get(int id)
 {
   // some stuff
 }
```

Here is the solution which I created, which does not work.

```
[HttpGet]
 [AuthoriseUser(  AllowedRoles = new[] { Enum.GetNames(typeof(Role)).Cast<Role>().Where(r => r != Role.Undefined) } )]
 public <anyreturnType> Get(int id)
 {
   // some stuff
 }
```

Error I am getting is

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[]' to
>   'Model.Role[]'

AuthoriseUserAttribute Class looks something like this.

```
   public class AuthoriseUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    { 
        public Role[] AllowedRoles { get; set; }
    .....more stuff here....
    }
```

When I used solution recommend by @Camilo Terevinto and further by @ejohnson
I get following error

[image]

Comment: Remove `new[] { }` and add `.ToArray()` after `.Where()`

Comment: Error CS0182 An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Comment: You could add an `All` value to your enum (with its value being the combination of all other enum member values). Then you could do something like `Role.All & ~Role.Undefined`. Or if you want to assgn all roles except Undefined and Private, you could do something like this `Role.All & ~(Role.Undefined | Role.Private)`, for example...

Answer (score 0):

[Camilo Terevinto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141621/camilo-terevinto) was correct, except you also need to use `Enum.GetValues` instead of `Enum.GetNames` (which returns strings):

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Role)).Cast<Role>().Where(r => r != Role.Undefined).ToArray()
```

Comment: Thanks @ejohnson, As mentioned above in comments it is throwing following error when used. See attached screenshot in question. 
Error CS0182 An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Comment: Sorry, I missed that the first time around; you're right that it doesn't compile as an attribute property. I think your best bet is to do something like @elgonzo suggested and turn your Enum values into bitwise flags.